# ASP.net credit card processing

Tags: asp.net, paypal, gateway

I have created a webstore with paypal gateway, but my client changed his mind and wants beside paypal, users to be able to pay with credit cards directly on the website. So I need opinions which framework to implement. I'm thinking of PayPal Pro solution, can someone explain me some details about it?

Comment: It's not really a programming question, what you need is for your client to pick a payment processor and then implement them. If you care about PCI (you should) then use a processor such as PayPal/Stripe/BrainTree/WePay/[Whatever] which handles the actual CC input and then just tells you if it worked or not. CC processors charge different rates to different people and there are legal obligations in using any of them so it's important that the client picks.

Comment: I understand that, but in my case is up to me what I'm going to use, my client just want payments to be made on the website, not to be redirected to the payment gateway, also my client doesnt have any IT knowledge of how thinks works. First think I thought was PayPal Pro.